# How to fix '_this4.props.handleExport' error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a `handleExport` function in the parent component set in a child under child component. However, the error below occurs and that would not work well.

> _this4.props._handleExport is not a function

`src/components/PrimaryItem.js`

```
export default class PrimaryItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stage
        ref={ref => {
          this.props._handleExport(ref);
        }}
      >
      </Stage>
    );
  }
}
```

`src/components/PrimaryContainer.js`

```
import PrimaryItem from "./PrimaryItem";


<PrimaryContainer
  _handleExport={this._handleExport}
/>
```

`src.App.js`

```
import PrimaryItem from "./components/PrimaryContainer";

export default class App extends component {
  _handleExport = ref => {
    if (ref) {
      this.refStage = ref;
    }
  };
  render() {

  return(
  <PrimaryContainer 
    _handleExport={this._handleExport}
  />
  )
}
}
```

Comment: You should change to use camel case for props in react _handleExport -> handleExport. See in [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: If your code is really as it is then it is very wrong. But you probably just have omitted stuff. However, we cannot really help in this case. You are saying that `src/components/PrimaryContainer.js` contains the code `<PrimaryContainer _handleExport={this._handleExport} />` but `PrimaryContainer` is not defined in that file and neither is `this._handleExport`. I'm also curious what you expect `this` to refer to here.

Comment: Do you at least understand what the error means? It means that you are passing the value `undefined` to `_handleExport={...}` somewhere. That would happen for example if you try to access a property that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bubble up requests through props passed into child containers like so.

```
// --- parent.js

import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { ChildComponent } from './containers/child'

export class ParentContainer extends Component {

  handleUpdate = () => {
    // whatever you want to do here
    console.log('I have been clicked from ChildContainer')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ChildComponent onUpdate={this.handleUpdate} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// --- child.js

import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

export class ChildComponent extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    console.log(this.props) // will show you the props you have access to pass into components.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onUpdate}></button>
    );
  }
}
```